# Excel Filter Function - Is there way to Dynamically Create Fields Based off Result

Tags: excel, function, filter, dynamic

So this is just more of a general question. When you use the Filter Function in Excel and it returns a result. Is there a way to dynamically create fields based on the result. What I don't want to do is just have a bunch of If("Value in this cell","Do this","Else Blank"). Like can you store it in a table and have formulas in the table fields? Anyone have any solutions to this or is just a long list of if statements the only way?

Comment: Perhaps index(), match() with large() for top 5 or 10. Some example data with expected results will make the question clearer.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Post few sample data and then explain what you want.